# jQuery get actual data-id from selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  a selector on webpage  with data-id and value

***HTML***

```html
    <select id="s1">
        <option data-id="01">aaaa1</option>
        <option data-id="23">bbb1</option>
        <option data-id="451">ccc1</option>
        <option data-id="56">ddd1</option>

    </select>

<p></p>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```js
$('#s1').change(function() { 
       var val = $(this).val();   
       var val_id =$(this).find('option').data('id');
       $("p").html("value = " + val + "<br>" +"value-data-id = "+  val_id);
});
```

I wanna  have actual value from selected selector and his data-id. I do not understand why I have data-id from only  first option. This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/s55rR/
Please help me to find a bug.

Comment: did you try with a more conservative `.attr("data-id")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `$(this).find('option:selected').data('id')`.

Answer (score 4):

**You've selected multiple elements** (`$(this).find('option')`) but [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) only returns the value from the first element if called on a jQuery with length >1:

> **Description:** *Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by `data(name, value)` or by an HTML5 `data-*` attribute.*

If you only want the `data-id` value from the user-selected`<option>`, then you need to select only that element.

Answer (score 3):

Because you selecting all options, and jQuery returning `.data('id')` of first one

```
var val_id =$(this).find('option:selected').data('id');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s55rR/1/)